# Allure report generation error for selenium webdriverio and mocha

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, allure

I am currently using Webdriver.io on top of selenium webdriver to write tests for my reactjs frontend. Tests run correctly using the default dot error reporter. When I use allure reporter(http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/allure.html), the json files are created. However when I try to generate an HTML report, I get a NumberFormatException error. The full error is shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:453)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:540)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseLong(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:114)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.Step_JaxbXducedAccessor_stop.parse(TransducedAccessor_field_Long.java:48)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:537)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:516)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:125)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:242)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.commons.AllureFileUtils.unmarshal(AllureFileUtils.java:59)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.commons.AllureFileUtils.unmarshal(AllureFileUtils.java:50)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.commons.AllureFileUtils.unmarshal(AllureFileUtils.java:40)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.io.TestSuiteReader$TestSuiteResultIterator.next(TestSuiteReader.java:48)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.io.TestSuiteReader$TestSuiteResultIterator.next(TestSuiteReader.java:1)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.io.TestCaseReader$TestCaseResultIterator.nextSuite(TestCaseReader.java:46)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.io.TestCaseReader$TestCaseResultIterator.hasNext(TestCaseReader.java:56)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:57)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:53)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureMain.main(AllureMain.java:48)
Command aborted due to exception {}.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.runUnsafe(ReportGenerate.java:48)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:52)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:46)
```

What could be the reason for this error? Need help.

Comment: What Allure version do you use? What tool do you use to generate report from allure results.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. It only seems to be certain tests that cause it.

Comment: Have a look at this page. https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1432